# How to Delete Subscribers From All Subscribers list

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, sfmc-business-unit

In my account have 1 million subscribers are available, i want to delete ALL Subscribers, From **Email > subscribers > all subscribers** (here i have 1 million) subscribers how to delete all subscribers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a list in your parent Business Unit: Email Studio > Subscribers > Lists

Then import the subscribers you want to delete into this list.

Then, delete this list and check the box to delete the Subscribers from All Subscribers.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you just want to delete all subscribers? There are few reasons why I will recommend you using the [Contact Deletion Framework](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_deletion_marketing.htm&type=5):

1. Deleting from All Subscribers will not necessarily remove the subscriber from billable contacts. And it will still count towards your utilisation.
2. Sendable data extensions might also contain traces of these contacts, posing a risk from PII/GDPR respective
3. Removing from All Subscribers list will still keep the tracking data in your account, which may include PII

Contact Deletion Framework will of course, as well, remove the subscriber data from All Subscribers

Comment: I'm familiar with this approach however I noticed a quick test revealed it did not remove a subscriber from All subs existing in a Held Status. (Not sure about Bounced). What expectation should be had when attempting to delete old unengaged active or inactive subscribers using this approach. It complies with #3...(We still want to maintain our tracking for deletions ...at least at the sends level even if the user tracking got lost at the address history) however, it doesn't always remove records for other reasons such in progress or sends. Would be nice to know constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I have understood that removing a subscriber from the all contacts list, will still prevent future sendings to that subscriber. As at the background the subscriber is not completely removed.

We encountered this when we removed from the all subscriber list a large number of contacts, which we no longer had present in our Sales Cloud environment. By accident we removed a few too many from the all subscribers list and there are now not receiving mailings anymore. There is no new subscriber created, it seems, when a contact is targetted again.